# How to display data from custom table in wordpress phpmyadmin

Tags: php, shortcode, mysql, phpmyadmin

Thanks in advance could anyone here help me, I would like to display the value from the phpmyadmin database in wordpress, The value was stored from the dropdown form and I want display that value in the page, I have used the following code and it working fine, just want to display the sum of pledges from the columns.

Following is the code and I want to display the sum of the pledges value stored in the phpmyadmin, it's the dropdown value so please help me

```
<?php 

add_shortcode('displ_tb', function(){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix_pl . 'wp_vxcf_leads_detail';
// this will get the data from your table
$dispdb_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from $table_name" );
foreach ($dispdb_data as $dispdb_data){ 
    $pledge = $dispdb_data->value;
    $lead_id = $dispdb_data->lead_id;
}
    $output = '<div class="wrap">
                    <h2>Pledges.</h2>
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Total Pledge</th>
                        <th>Live Count</th>
                      </tr> 
                      <tr>
                        <td>'. $pledge .'</td>
                        <td>'. $lead_id .'</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>            
                </div>';
    return $output;
} );

?>
```

[image: In this following image I want to display the sum of the pledge each time user add the pledge it should increse]

Comment: I want to display sum of the pledge column values stored in the phpmyadmin

Comment: The problem you're going to encounter is that you're saving the pledge values as strings like `1000 Pledge` and `300 Pledge`.  Your task would be a lot simpler if you were to change the input portion of this to record the pledge values at integers instead.  As it stands now, you have to gather all the pledge value records, then remove the numbers from the string and place them in separate variables, then add all of those variables to an array, then sum all of the variables in that array.  That's a really unnecessarily complex process.

Comment: Thanks Tony for reply, It's wordpress phpmyadmin and here I am using contact form 7 to store the values so all the checkboxes, dropdowns & radio buttons are stored as strings so need to know how to display their sum Value

Comment: That's fine, but if you store a string like `300`, then when you pull that from the database you can very easily just convert it to an integer like `(int)$pledge`. BUT, if what you save in the database is `300 Pledge` you're not going to be able to use `(int)$pledge` anymore because it won't know what to do with those extra characters.
So can you change what Contact Form 7 saves to the database by removing the extra words and spaces?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried but still CF7 stores string value only so unable to fetch the integer value from the column and sum it

Comment: It's ok if CF7 stores the value as a string, but are you able to just make the string `300` and nothing more?  A string that is just numbers is fine, a string that is a combination of numbers and spaces and letters will be harder to parse and sum.

Comment: Yes I have made it as integer now just 300,500.. and stored in the row = "pledge-test" now how to calculate sum of all pledge-test and display it. we are using two columns "name" & "value" in a name column row is "pledge-test" and in value it's actual value so how to modify above code to display the sum of the all pledge-test

Comment: Thanks for the help I managed to resolve the question. Thanks a ton!